# ExpressJS + AngularJS: communicate routes and controllers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have a `json` object in my `express.js` routes file and in order to parse it, I am guessing that the best way would be to send to my Angular `controller` to be looped in my view.

**routes/myaccount.js**

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  // form submitted
  var email = req.body.email
  var password = req.body.password
  login.returnSessionToken(email, password, (token) => {
      console.log("return token: ", token)
      var logged = require('../js/index')
      logged.returnUserData(token, (myData) => {
        res.render('myaccount', { myDataFromRoutes:myData });
      })

    },
  (fail) => {console.log(fail)})

})
```

**controller.js**

```
var controllers = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

controllers.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data= myDataFromRoutes; //how do I get the JSON object from my routes and pass it here?
}]);
```

**myaccount.html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="IndexController">
        <li ng-repeat="d in data">
          {{ d }}
        </li>
   </div>
</body>
```

Is the structure right? I can't figure how to make my express routes communicate with my angular controller.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using `$http` to AJAX the JSON object, you can use `ngInit`. This is one of the few intended uses of `ngInit`. Use Jade or whatever server template engine you have to interpolate the JSON object in the `ng-init` directive:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="IndexController" ng-init="data = #{JSON.stringify(myDataFromRoutes)}">
        <li ng-repeat="d in data">
          {{d}}
        </li>
   </div>
</body>
```

Since you are operating inside the controller's scope, the data variable will also be available in your controller as `$scope.data`.

Alternatively, (probably better, actually) you can interpolate directly in the JavaScript. But this, won't work for JS included as a file. It will have to be an inline script:

```
<script>
  var controllers = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
  controllers.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data= #{JSON.stringify(myDataFromRoutes)};
  }]);
</script>
```

**NOTE:** Recent versions of Pug have replaced the above interpolation syntax with the following:

```
ng-init="data = `${JSON.stringify(myDataFromRoutes)}`"
```

Comment: Getting `Argument 'IndexController' is not a function, got undefined` for some reason. Also, is it `myData` or `myDataFromRoutes`?

Comment: You may need to `.stringify()` the JSON object. You may also be able to interpolate directly into the controller's js file.

Comment: Getting error: `myData is not defined` on `controller.js`. How does it know that `myData` is coming from the `express.js` router?

Comment: Angular has no idea about the name of the variable `myData`, but Express will interpolate `myData` so that when the page is rendered, Angular will see the raw JSON: `data = { "prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", etc....}`

Comment: I also had the variable name wrong. It should be `myDataFromRoutes`, not `myData`